# How would I select and display the most recently added rows from a SQL table?

Tags: php, sql

I am making an extremely basic posting system, and I cant seem to figure out how to get the most recent rows from a certain table. I have tried other solutions offered here, but my posts were randomly placed. How would I accomplish this? My code is below.

```
function load_posts(){
$posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $posts_result = Phoenix\Database\Database::$database->query($posts_sql);
    while($row = $posts_result->fetch_assoc()){
        $posts_display = '

        <div class = "card" style = "width:500px">
            <div class = "card-body">
            <div class = "card-title">'. $row['username'] .'</div>
            <p>'. $row['content'] .'</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        ';

        echo $posts_display;
        }
}
```

Again, I want the posts to be displayed from most recent, to old.

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: Why not just use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: What specific relational database are you using? Tag your question with the specific RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have information in each row that captures this information.  The most common suspects are:

- an auto-incrementing id
- a creation date

Then you just ask the database to sort the results.  For instance, if `post_id` is an auto-incremented id:

```
select p.*
from posts p
order by p.post_id;
```

Comment: My post_ids are based on the user_id, so if I add an auto-increment to post_id, I wont get any errors if there are two of the same values in the post_id column?

Comment: @Neutron . . . I simply don't understand the question in the comment.  `user_id`s don't have anything to do with your question or this answer.  Whether what you say would generate an error depends on many factors, such as your data model and the query your referring to.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY id DESC

// order by should be with primary key